# Using logical OR with cout operator

Tags: c++, operator-precedence

Why `bitor` doesn't work while using it with `cout` operator

This works

```
int a=5,b = 6,d = a bitor b;
cout << d << endl;
```

This is throwing error

```
int a=5,b=6;
cout << a bitor b << endl;
```

error message:

```
invalid operands of types 'int' and '<unresolved overloaded function type>' to binary 'operator<<'
  cout << a bitor b << endl;
```

Comment: Works for me with braces around it, like `(a bitor b)`, so I guess it's an operator precedence issue.

Comment: Side note: It's more common to use `|` instead of `bitor` in C++. Your code confused me a lot at first glance.

Comment: Note that `std::cout` is not an operator. It's an object. The `<<` is an operator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [Operator Precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), `operator<<` has higher precedence than `operator bitor`. Then `cout << a bitor b << endl;` will be interpreted as

```
(cout << a) bitor (b << endl);
```

while `b << endl` is invalid.

You can add parentheses to specify the correct precedence, e.g.

```
cout << (a bitor b ) << endl;
```